# Displaying associated records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view, model

I have a `User`, `List`, and `Task` models.

A **task** `belongs_to` *user* and *list*, a *list* `has_many` *tasks* and `belongs_to` *user*, and a *user* `has_many` *list* and `has_many` *tasks*.

I have part of what I want to display working in my index view, with just one snafu that I am getting hung up on.

I'm able to display the first created task in the index view of all the lists. The problem is, the first task created is displayed for all of the lists, even if the list is NOT associated with the task.

In the list index view I want the first task created to display only if it is associated with the list.

Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :completed, :description, :list_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user

  scope :completed, where(:completed => true)
  scope :incomplete, where(:completed => false)

  def self.most_recent
    first(:order => 'id ASC' ) # or whatever query you need to get the most recent
  end

end
```

List Index View-

```
<div class="span12 offset2"> 
 <% @lists.each do |list| %> 
  <div class="well row span4">
    <div class="span3">
    </div>  
    <div class="span4">   
      <span class="lead">
        <%= link_to "#{list.name}", list_url(list) %>
      </span>
      <p>
        <%= list.description %>
      </p><hr>
      <div class="pull-right" id="gage-<%= list.id %>" style="width:170px; height:100px;"></div>
      <br>  
      <span class="offset1">
        <% if Task.most_recent %>
          <span class="pull-left"> <%= image_tag Task.most_recent.user.gravatar_url, :class => "gravatar_index" %></span>
        <% end %>  
      </span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm still new to rails but I know I'm very close. What am I overlooking here? *emphasized text*

===========

## **EDIT**

I've tested @Baldrick's solution and now seem to be getting another error

My view with described solution-

```
<% if Task.most_recent(list) %>
      <span class="pull-left"> <%= image_tag Task.most_recent.user.gravatar_url, :class => "gravatar_index" %></span>
<% end %>
```

I am now getting the error-

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.list: SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."list" = 4 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

I must not be understanding correctly because I have such a created column when I created the Task model

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :description
      t.boolean :completed, :default => false
      t.integer :list_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is this a case where I need to add an index to be able to make my query?

Comment: Is the missing `<% end %>` for the each block just a typo?

Comment: That's correct it was left off on the c and p.

Comment: It's complaining because of list used instead of list_id. It's because there is an error in @Baldrick's code. In the most_recent method, the method sould be like the one I've put in my answer as a first option. Using Baldrick's code, it should be `where(list_id: list).order('id ASC').first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `most_recent` gives you the last create task of *all* tasks. What you wnat is the most recent task of a given list.

You should give a parameter to the list

```
def self.most_recent(list)
  where(list_id: list.id).order('id ASC').first # or whatever query you need to get the most recent
end
```

Comment: and my view would be the same except passing list as a parameter `Task.most_recent(list)`?

Comment: This is the solution I ultimately went with. Please see @jtblin comment on this solution as it was the only way I got this solution to work.

Comment: Should this be `where(list_id: list.id)` or can you really just do `where(list_id: list)`?

Comment: I'm not sure, so I edited the answer with `list_id: list.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `most_recent` method returns the first task of Task. There is nothing in this method tying the task to any list. You'd need to pass the list_id to this method to get the first task for this list, e.g.

```
def self.most_recent(list_id)
    first(:order => 'id ASC', :list_id => list_id) 
end
```

Edit: other solution didn't work.

Comment: getting a `undefined method `most_recent' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8cb9bcc030>` error for this. In my view I would now have `<%= image_tag list.tasks.most_recent.user.gravatar_url, :class => "gravatar_index" %>`

Comment: Ok, I kept the first option only, please try it as-is, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it does *not* sound like you want, for each list, to show the most recent task for that list.  Rather, it seems you want to have the *overall* most recent task to appear multiple times, once for each list that happens to contain it.  To achieve this you want to replace `if Task.most_recent` with `if list.tasks.include? Task.most_recent`.

---EDIT---

Okay, if you actually want to show, for each list, *that list's* most recent task, then you should be going about this fairly differently.  In your `List` class you should have the following method:

```
def most_recent_task
    tasks.first(:order => 'id ASC') # or whatever
end
```

Then in your view you'll replace both occurrences of `Task.most_recent` with `list.most_recent_task`.  And if your lists will always have at least one task, then you can get rid of the guard clause (i.e. the `if`) altogether.

As a further refactor you may want to take some computation out of the view, and create "presenters" for your lists index, which would just be an array of presenters for each individual list.  An individual presenter should be a plain object with the information you need about the list, precomputed:

- name
- url
- description
- most recent task's user's gravatar url

Comment: This is not how I wanted to come across. I want it to be as though you have separate lists unrelated to one another and thus the tasks would be unrelated. I DO want show the most recent task for that list :)

Comment: yes this is likely the approach I will take once I refactor which as I understand, convention and workflow wise, should be done sooner than later. That said, thanks for adding to your answer.